How to simultaneously execute 2 turtlesims inthe same window
I have a simple turtlesim program with me and was trying to run it with roslaunch. I wanted to have 2 turtlesims in the same window and a common python script to execute both the new nodes created simultaneously. I tried changing the script but apparently both turtlesims are running on separate windows. I saw something else online. My roslaunch file is as follows:
<launch>
  <node name="turtlesim" pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" output="screen" args="5 5 0 turtlesim" />
    <!-- Spawn a new turtle -->
  <node name="spawn_turtle" pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" respawn="true" output="screen" args="2 2 0 spawn_turtle" />
  <node name="clean_node" pkg="ros_essentials_cpp" type="turtlesim_cleaner.py" output='screen'/>
</launch>

The turtlesim_cleaner seems to work just fine when only one turtlesim node is launched.
What needs to be done or modified? I am new to ROS1.

You are starting two turtlesim nodes, which will have a window each. However, if you just start the first and then call the spawn service on that node, you will get a second turtle in the window.
Here is some guidance documentation: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim
I gather you want to use ROS 1? You should be able to do the same in ROS 2, though.
